# iOS, how to convert mp4 file into ts (transport stream) without ffmpeg?

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, mp4, transport-stream

as I described in title, I need to convert mp4 file to ts file, but without using ffmpeg library. Is it possible to do by native API? Where should I look to?